# Are there narrative structures other than Kishōtenketsu and the three act structure and its derivatives?

Tags: structure, narrative

Derivatives of the three act structure include the Hero's journey, Dan Harmon's story circle, and the five act structure.

Answer (score 4):

[Terry Pratchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett) had a good go at a one act structure. His narratives often tended towards a certain flatness in which all parts of the tale have approximately equal tension and about the same value to the story as a whole. They tended, in reality, to actually have two acts one that started at the beginning and took the majority of the book and a much shorter one that showed people getting back to "business as usual"; that was often a couple of pages or less.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't read any of his books. Is this something he talked about about in a book or interview somewhere? Or is this just something you have extrapolated from his books?

Comment: @WilliamOliver Not that I'm aware of, Terry Pratchett was pretty vocal when it came to denying that he was any good at writing at all and usually refused to give advice on the matter. This is just my experience of reading a lot of his Discworld books.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's out of subject, but a joke has a two part structure (my source is the Netflix's Nanette show but I'm sure you can find others).

A story "of which you are the hero" might also have a different structure (I absolutely don't know, but it could be a good idea to take a look into it).

If you want to find other narrative structure, you would probably have better luck looking into "non-typical" story, like poetry, theater, opera, ballet, etc...

Anyway, good luck finding other structures. Sometime, it feels like even the Kishōtenketsu doesn't exist (especially when you read an article saying: "the narrative structure is *always* the same").